# io multiplexing ,server does not receive the data

Tags: c, unix, client-server, multiplexing

I'm writing a multiplexed client/server and my server ,after receiving the LOGIN command from the client ,waits account data ,but receives an empty struct and I don't know why. this is my code:
[Server:](http://codepad.org/Q4tU6RyK)

[autentica function:](http://codepad.org/J9HtzTxw)

[client login function:](http://codepad.org/wCwenevV)

I tried to use the function sleep (), but it did not work.
any suggestions?

Comment: Are you using TCP?  If so, you need to carefully check how many bytes you actually read - TCP is prone to partial `read()`'s.  And TCP is a stream - that means when you read you can get the results of more than one `write()` from the other end of the connection.

Comment: Should I use fullWrite and Fullread?

Answer (score 1):

I have not seen all the code because here is night!!! :)

But I see that the code of the function autentica (autentica.c) seems uses strcmp in a wrong way! I think this could be a problem!

It is:

```
 while (!feof(file)) {//legge finchè non finisce il file
        fread(&acc_to_cmp, sizeof(acc_to_cmp), 1, file);//recupera un account dal file
        if (strcmp(account.matricola, acc_to_cmp.matricola)) {//se l'utente esiste
            if (strcmp(account.password, acc_to_cmp.password)) {//controlla la password
                write(fd, (comm_t *)OK, sizeof(comm_t));//se coincidono concedi l'accesso
                fclose(file);
                return 1;
            }
            else{//se non coincidono
                write(fd, (comm_t *)WRONG_PASS, sizeof(comm_t));//nega l'accesso
                fclose(file);
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }//se l'utente non esiste
```

I think it should be:

```
 while (!feof(file)) {//legge finchè non finisce il file
        fread(&acc_to_cmp, sizeof(acc_to_cmp), 1, file);//recupera un account dal file
        if (!strcmp(account.matricola, acc_to_cmp.matricola)) {//se l'utente esiste
            if (!strcmp(account.password, acc_to_cmp.password)) {//controlla la password
                write(fd, (comm_t *)OK, sizeof(comm_t));//se coincidono concedi l'accesso
                fclose(file);
                return 1;
            }
            else{//se non coincidono
                write(fd, (comm_t *)WRONG_PASS, sizeof(comm_t));//nega l'accesso
                fclose(file);
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }//se l'utente non esiste
```

The strcmp function returns 0 when the two string are equal! :)

Comment: The real problem is the first `read()` function because it should receive an account but it receive bad data.

Comment: I cannot know this! I hope you solved! But see the autentica function cause strcmp returns 0 when the string are equal!

Comment: you're right about this, thanks, I've solved a problem that would be presented further

Comment: If you're in Italy (I think so) ... good job-night else good job!

Comment: We have the same "luck" ;)

Answer (score 0):

May be in

```
    if( (fd = accept(......)) <0)
```

I think this assignment wouble also cause problems and some times you don't know them how to run in the application.You can do the assingment before the judgment.Of course,this is my idea about that.Because I have had the same problem.
I hope this is helpful to you.Or help you find the way to solve it. Tell me,Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Resolved! The problem was I was passing in the first write() a constant: `write(socket, (comm_t *)LOGIN, sizeof(comm_t));` 
while i had to first save "LOGIN" in a variable and then pass it in this way: `write(socket, &command, sizeof(comm_t));`